# EnableDelayedExpansion only works for first command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

After ApkTool executes the !name! variable no longer expands as expected. I'm not sure what's going on here nor how to fix it.

```
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"
for %%I in ("%~1") do (
set name="..\Compiled_apk\%%~nxI"
apktool b "%%~I" -f -o "!name!.apk"
zipalign -f 4 "!name!.apk" "!name!.temp"
del "!name!.apk"
ren "!name!.temp" "!name!.apk"
apksigner sign -v --key "..\Program_Files\testkey.pk8" --cert "..\Program_Files\testkey.x509.pem" "!name!.apk"
)
exit
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `apktool` is a script and since you're not using `call`, control never comes back to the main script after that point. If `apktool` is a regular exe file, I've never heard of this happening and I don't understand how it's even possible.

Comment: @SomethingDark, it is a batch file. Your comment is correct.

Comment: You wouldn't need to use delayed expansion if you just used the FOR variable by itself.  Regardless, that was not the problem with your script.

Comment: Thanks, please post that as an answer. I've never tried to call another batch with delayed expansion enabled so I had no idea that could happen. Squashman, I agree, but this is only one of several scripts - it's just a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a second batch script without using `call`, the original script stops and control is transferred to the second script. Once the second script finishes, control does not return to the original script (since it is stopped).

However, if you use `call` to start the second script, the original script pauses and control is only temporarily handed to the second script. Once the second script finishes, control returns to the original script and it picks up where it left off.

```
apktool b "%%~I" -f -o "!name!.apk"
```

Google suggests that `zipalign` and `apksigner` are actual executables, so you don't need to call those.